# xmm, cmp two 32-bit float

Tags: assembly, floating-point, sse

I'm trying to understand how to compare two floating point numbers (32-bit) using the xmm registers.
To test I've written this code in C (which calls the code in assembly):

```
#include "stdio.h"

extern int compare();

int main()
{

    printf("Result: %d\n", compare());

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the assembly, I want to test if b < c, in this case it does
and the code should return 1, but it returns 0:

```
section .data

a:  dd 5.5555
b:  dd 1.1111
c:  dd 5.5555

section .text

global compare

compare:
            ; -------------------------------------------
            ; Entrace sequence
            ; -------------------------------------------
            push    ebp         ; save base pointer
            mov     ebp, esp    ; point to current stack frame 
            push    ebx         ; save general registers
            push    ecx
            push    edx
            push    esi         
            push    edi

            movss xmm0, [b]
            movss xmm1, [c]
            comiss xmm0, xmm1
            jl change
            mov eax, 0
            jmp end
change:
            mov eax, 1
end:
            ; ------------------------------------------
            ; Exit sequence
            ; ------------------------------------------

            pop     edi
            pop     esi
            pop     edx
            pop     ecx
            pop     ebx
            mov     esp, ebp
            pop     ebp
            ret
```

If I try to use jg it returns 1, but I think it should be the opposite, xmm0 is less than xmm1.

If I write

```
movss xmm0, [b]
comiss xmm0, [b]
je change
```

It return 1, as expected.
Does someone know why it is behaving in this way? Maybe I'm not using the proper jump instructions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use the JB and JA (jump below/above) instructions instead of JL/JG. The COMISS instruction sets the flags as if it were two unsigned integers being compared. This makes the effect on the flags simpler.

The COMISS instruction's effect on flags is documented in the Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual as:

> ```
> RESULT ← OrderedCompare(SRC1[31:0] ≠ SRC2[31:0]) {
> (* Set EFLAGS *) CASE (RESULT) OF
>     UNORDERED:           ZF,PF,CF ← 111;
>     GREATER_THAN:        ZF,PF,CF ← 000;
>     LESS_THAN:           ZF,PF,CF ← 001;
>     EQUAL:               ZF,PF,CF ← 100;
> ESAC;
> OF,AF,SF ← 0; }
> ```

While the branch instructions are documented as:

> ```
> 77 cb    JA rel8   ...   Jump short if above (CF=0 and ZF=0).
> 72 cb    JB rel8   ...   Jump short if below (CF=1).
> 7F cb    JG rel8   ...   Jump short if greater (ZF=0 and SF=OF).
> 7C cb    JL rel8   ...   Jump short if less (SF≠ OF).
> ```

The JB/JA test the flags that are set according to the the result of the operation, while JL/JG test flags that are always set to 0.

Comment: @AR89 Yup. The ZF flag is set when they're the equal.